# Matrix of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $J=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right)$ and $E=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right) \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) : a - d=0\right\}$
We define the application $\varphi: E \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all M,N$\in E, \varphi(M,N)=Tr(M J N)$.
I was asked to prove that $B=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ll}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ll}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)\right\}$ is a basis of $E$.
But now i want to figure out the matrix of the associated quadratic form q (I was asked to prove that $\varphi$ is symmetric bilinear too).
One way to do this is to compute $\varphi(e_{i};e_{j})$ where $e_{i}, e_{j}$ are vectors of the basis B of E:
$\varphi\left(I_{2}, I_{2}\right)=Tr\left(I_{2} J I_{2}\right)=\operatorname{Tr}(J)=0$ ;
$\varphi\left(E_{2,2} , E_{2,2}\right)=0$ ;
$\varphi\left(E_{3,3}, E_{3,3}\right)=0$ ; $\varphi\left(I_{2} ; E_{2,2}\right)=\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left(\begin{array}{ll}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\right)=1$ ; $\varphi\left(I_{3} ; E_{3,3}\right)=\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}1& 0 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right)\right)=1$ ; $\varphi\left(E_{2,2} ; E_{3,3}\right)=Tr\left(E_{2,2} J E_{3,3}\right)=Tr\left(\left(\begin{array}{ll}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\right)=-1 .$
$Thus A=Mat_{B}(\varphi)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1& -1 & 0\end{array}\right)$. On the other hand i wanted to find the matrix of q starting from the matrix expression of q(M). $q(M)=Tr(MJM)=Tr\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & a\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & a\end{array}\right)\right]=Tr\left(\begin{array}{ll}a^{2}+a c+a b-b c & a b+a^{2}+b^{2}-a b \\ a c+c^{2}+a^{2}-a c & b c+a c+a b-a^{2}\end{array}\right)$
$\begin{aligned} q(M)=& 2 a b+2 a c \\ \varphi(M ; N) &=a b^{\prime}+a^{\prime} b+a c^{\prime}+a^{\prime} c \\ &=a\left(b^{\prime}+c^{\prime}\right)+b\left(a^{\prime}\right)+c\left(a^{\prime}\right) \\ \varphi(M ; N) &=(a \quad b \quad c) \quad\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}a^{\prime} \\ b^{\prime} \\ c^{\prime}\end{array}\right) \end{aligned}$.
Here is the problem! The matrix A of q is not the same as previous. And i really really  don't see where is the problem. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Both your calculations are "correct" but unfortunately $\varphi$ is not symmetric. In the first calculation, you only calculated the upper triangular part of the representing matrix and got it right and deduced the lower part by symmetry and got the wrong answer since $\varphi$ is not symmetric. In the second calculation you looked at the quadratic form defined by $\varphi$ but it is actually the same as the quadratic form defined by the symmetric part of $\varphi$ which you calculated again correctly but it is not the representing matrix of $\varphi$ (since again, $\varphi$ is not symmetric)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, $\varphi$ is **not** symmetric. In fact, using the cyclic property of trace, we have
\begin{aligned}
\varphi\left(\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}\right)
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}\right)
=-1
\end{aligned}
while
\begin{aligned}
\varphi\left(\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0},\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\right)
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\right)
=1.
\end{aligned}
With respect to the basis mentioned in your question, the correct matrix representation of $\varphi$ is
$$
M=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&-1\\ 1&1&0}
$$
which gives rise to the same quadratic form represented by
$$
\frac12(M+M^T)=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 1&0&0}.
$$
There is probably a typo in the question. I think the author wanted to define $\varphi(M,N)$ as $\operatorname{tr}(MJN^T)$ (or $\operatorname{tr}(M^TJN)$) instead, so that
$$
\varphi(M,N)
=\operatorname{tr}(MJN^T)
=\operatorname{tr}\left((MJN^T)^T\right)
=\operatorname{tr}(NJM^T)
=\varphi(N,M).
$$